# Embedded Jetty - role issue

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jaas

I am using embedded jetty with my application, in which I migrated from 6 to 9 version, which has more complexity in terms of implementation.

For JAASUserRealm now as JAASLoginService - not sure about how to setRoleName classes for LoginSevice

tried with User,Principal, etc.,

Comment: Pro Tip: don't use the embedded Jetty if you have any specific need. Use an external server configured to your needs, and then [run DevMode in `-noserver` mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer : I need this embedded Jetty for Server-Client of my application. I resolved with setRoleClass with my security Principal class

Comment: I am facing issues with JAAS LoginModule.. can you help/comment on it.. using Jetty 9.1.1 version

Comment: Oh sorry, I though you were using the Jetty server that's embedded in GWT DevMode. Let's remove the 'gwt' tag then.

Comment: okay.. actually GWT app (client ) - Server (uses embedded Jetty ) with JAAS for authentication.. have any idea on this combination ?? tip on this greatly helpful